# Trakhound agent displaying UNAVAILABLE items

Tags: c#, .net, mtconnect

I'm creating a Wpf C# .NET 8 app using the MTConnect.NET-SHDR 6.0.9-beta package. I'm publishing on the local network some dataitems, and they are correctly displayed if the sequence number is greater than a certain amount (otherwise the value is UNAVAILABLE). I think the problem is with the version of .NET, because it is not supported, but I'm not sure because using a previous version of TrakHound every dataitem value is displayed correctly (I tried locally).

```
//code for updating adapter 
 myAdapter = new ShdrAdapter("Dreno");
 myAdapter.Start();

myAdapter.AddDataItem("StopRequest", UtilityTools.StopRequest);
//[...]
myAdapter.AddDataItem("CalibrationCompleted", UtilityTools.CalibrationCompleted);

myAdapter.SendChanged();
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbMBv.png)

As I said tried using Trakhound agent 5.4.3.0 and the data was displayed in a table format and there were no UNAVAILABLE items.